# How to draw an arbitrary curve in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, curve

I'm working on a game based on cocos2dx, now I need to draw an arbitrary curve as the finger moves on the screen,then the curve will become the path along which my hero walks.Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curve is connected line. 
so you can draw curve using connected line.

Accumulate the points in `cctouchesmove/cctouchemove` event function. 
Make line sprite, add and draw them.

and also cocos2d-x have curve classes. 
if you use them, you can run action easily.

```
CCCardinalSplineTo
CCCardinalSplineBy
CCCatmullRomTo
CCCatmullRomBy
CCBezierBy
CCBezierTo
```

And for drawing, this is sample code.

```
void HelloWorld::draw()  
{  
    // move to 50,50 since the "by" path will start at 50,50  
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    kmGLTranslatef(50, 50, 0);
    ccDrawCardinalSpline(m_pArray, 7, 100);

    kmGLPopMatrix();

    CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();  

    kmGLPushMatrix();  
    kmGLTranslatef(s.width/2, 50, 0);  
    ccDrawCardinalSpline(m_pArray, 1, 100);  
    kmGLPopMatrix();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I can now draw the curve with ccDrawCardinalSpline, but I also need to add some texture to the curve path,like a path of grass ,etc.I can't find a solution.

Comment: Curve texturing is a bit complicating problem. I am sure this reference will help you. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1